# Is it possible to create a hyperlink to a page that has Double quotes within the path?

Tags: php, html

I want to create hyperlinks to pages on my site but the page address have double quotes within them?

Eg:

```
<a href="mysite.com/search.php?q="sales+manager"&l=usa"></a>
```

the above just links to **mysite.com/search.php?q=** as I would expect as it is written.

The API returning results allows phrase searches by placing them in double quotes.

Is there a way to escape these within the href tag?

Comment: Have a look at html entities

Comment: use `urlencode`. Example : `href="?q=<?php echo urlencode('"sales+manager"') ?>&l=usa">Link</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: use altenative quotes:

```
<a href='mysite.com/search.php?q="sales+manager"&l=usa'></a>
```

This will work fine (the browser will make sure the URL gets properly formatted when a user clicks it), but you should really be urlencoding special characters because there's a whole bunch of stuff that you're not allowed to use in URLs, and some stuff that has a different meaning (in a URL, spaces become +, for instance, so you can't drop in a + and get it to stay that once you parse it. URL magic!).

Have a look at [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and use that when generating the link URL server side. This will turn things like spaces into `%20`, double quotes into `%22`, etc., and is how you send literal string data from a client to a server.

Comment: Url encoding is the way to go for my purposes. thanks mike Using @Paul suggestion <?php echo urlencode('mylink'); ?> within the <a href tag works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Yo must encode the quotes &quot

```
mysite.com/search.php?q=&quot;sales+manager&quot;&l=usa
```

Comment: missing a semicolon there `:)`  `&quot;`

Comment: but since it's a URL, you might as well just `urlencode` it, which means turning it into `%22`. Remember: this is a link, not HTML text, so &quot; might "work", but it's not actually correct.

Comment: I am urlencoding when the user enters their search term in my input field. how would I url encode within the a href for site links if I wanted this to be the proper way to do it?

Comment: Your right @Paul works perfect. clean in the address bar..thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to escape these within the href tag?

Yes, with the escape character.  `\`.

Although, the current state of your code would produce:

```
<a href="example.com/search.php?q="sales+manager"&l=usa"></a>
```

effectively breaking the href since you are breaking the string.

What you want, is just:

```
<a href="mysite.com/search.php?q=sales+manager&l=usa">...</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work because it returns results that have either sales OR manager where I need it to perform the phrase search.

Comment: hmm.. your question isn't very specific. could you include more information and code on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Phrase searches need double quotes to work per the API so using just the + sign returns different results.

Answer (score 0):

you are considering whether the characters need to be escaped in order to work in your HTML. 
however, you should also consider whether they need to be escaped in order to be sound URLs.

to work in  your HTML you may do
`<a href="mysite.com/search.php?q='sales+manager'&l=usa">`. 
however, the `'` character cannot be in a URL.

"Uniform Resource Locators may only contain the displayable characters in the standard ASCII character set. Nondisplayable characters or characters in the extended ASCII set (128 through 255) are specially encoded." 
See [here](http://www.ryerson.ca/perl/CGI/URLEncoding.html) for a list of URL escape codes.

perhaps you want to retain the quotes in the get-request of your URL. in that case, you might want:

```
<a href="mysite.com/search.php?q=%22sales+manager%22&l=usa">
```